# How to import com.google.android.gms.location;?

Tags: android, import

I am simply trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). I get errors when I do the import statements like "import com.google.android.gms.location;"

I have Google Play Services installed already, and I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the Google APIs for the specific version of the `Android` platform that you are using.

Then you have to set the `compile with` version for your `Android` project to `Google APIs`(`API` <`the api level you are targeting`>). Then you will be able to import it.